# Meaning of "I'll take a look at your septic tank, see if I can get her humming again."

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of this sentence? I know every word in the sentence but can't figure out the meaning of it.

> Flander: Homer, I'm in a rhubarb of a pickle of a jam here. I was all set to go
> off on vacation when I get called up for jury duty. Oh, it's a corker
> of a case. Seems a man drove up onto a traffic island and hit a
> decorative rowboat full of geraniums. Now they're trying it as a
> maritime offense. So, anyhoo, how'd you like to use my beach house,
> free of charge?
>
> Homer: I only get two weeks of vacation a year and you want
> me to spend it in your lousy beach house?
>
> Flander: Well, if it'll seal the deal
> **I'll take a look at your septic tank, see if I can get her humming
> again.**

Source: The Simpsons S07E25

http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?episode=s07e25

Comment: For what it's worth, a British person, such as myself, is likely to have taken this joke completely wrongly (the answers about machinery are correct). In BrE, "humming" is also slang for having a characteristic, poor odour.

Answer (score 9):

To get something "humming again" (such as a car, or a machine) means to bring it back into good repair from a broken state.  It implies that *moving parts* are working smoothly.  So it is meaningless  with respect to a septic tank, which has no moving parts. The humor derives from the incongruity.

Comment: In case this answer isn't completely clear: When a machine with moving parts is not working properly, it often makes clanking or banging noises. When it's running well, it makes something of a humming noise, a smooth, even tone. So to "get a machine humming" is to get it working properly.

Comment: In British English, 'humming' is also used to describe something that smells terrible.  I don't know if the scriptwriters intended the pun, but it did give me a laugh.

Comment: Another thing a non-native speaker might be unclear about is the use of "her" to refer to an inanimate object. It's not uncommon for people (especially men), to use "her" instead of "it" to refer to a machine (such as a car or boat) that they are fond of. So just to be clear, the "her" in this sentence refers to the septic tank, not a person.

Comment: Note that a septic tank itself, while it has no moving parts, also has a pump to move the... material up to a drainage field. This pump (a sump pump) does have moving parts and may make some noise while it is activated.

Comment: Septic tanks do have moving 'parts': the bacteria which perform digestion on the material moving through the system.  Also, many septic systems do not have pumps.

Comment: We had a gravity-fed septic tank with no pump when I was a kid and lived out in the boondocks. The bacteria weren't very noisy, as I recall :-)

Comment: @TRomano: True, but in this sense "humming" just implies working smoothly, not necessarily making any noise.

Comment: @ssav raises a very good point, this was the first thing i thought of.

Answer (score 5):

Just to provide a little more detail

> I'll take a look at your

"I am offering to investigate the problems with" or "I will try to fix"

> septic tank,

Some houses have a sewage treatment system - a septic tank - which is used instead of connecting to the main sewage system.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septic_tank

> see if I can get her humming again.

As described above "attempt to get it working".

The joke here is that Homer is being offered a *very* generous deal - he refuses - so Flanders literally offers to fix Homer's broken sewage system. A smelly and unpleasant job.